# Deleting all orphan subscriptions in PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

In Google PubSub, subscriptions to topics are not deleted when the topic itself is deleted.

Is there an easy way of deleting all orphan subscriptions? I have hundreds and can't do it manually.

Why are they not deleted with the topics in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the only solution I could find:

`gcloud alpha pubsub subscriptions list | grep "_deleted-topic_" > orphan-subscriptions`

Then use a text editor to put all the topics in the same line to run this command:

`gcloud alpha pubsub subscriptions delete <subscription1> <subscription2> <subscription3> ...`

It will delete 1 subscription per second.